# if $f’(0)$ or $f’(1)$ does not exist how to find norm

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

In the following problem from Kesavan’s Functional Analysis, I am having trouble to understand the meaning of the norm.
[image]

It is said that $||f||=max_{x\in[0,1]}\{|f(t)|,|f’(t)|\}.$

I suppose it means maximum of all values of $|f(t)|$ and $|f’(t)|$ in $[0,1].$

However if $f’(0)$ or $f’(1)$ does not exist how can I find $||f||$.

Comment: "and whose derivatives can be continuously extended to $[0,1]$"

Comment: So I have to consider the maximum of continuously extended function of f’? But that function is not f’ itself it is a different function which is the extension of f’. should not it then wrong to write max|f’| instead denoting it differently?

Answer (score 0):

The hypothesis says the derivatives can be extended continuously to the whole closed interval, they are bounded, and so these functions are Lipschitz, and hence uniformly continuous, so the values there can also be extended to the boundary with no issues.

So there's no problem defining either maxima.

Comment: As for as maximum of $|f'(t)|$ is concerned you can simply omit the values 0 and 1 for t.

Comment: That means supremum on (0,1)?